# Runtime Exceptiom: could not find class

Tags: java, android

When i try to test my application, suddenly i have unexpected exception and i don't know the reason yet, please help me to find the error.
 (the error was : `could not find class "com.example.MyPagerAdapter` " )

This is my code at second activity

**note**: this application just test the swipe in the i'm just define an adapter from class `MyPagerAdapter` and then define a ViewPager like this

```
 ViewPager   myPager   = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.home_pannels_pager);
```

then set the adapter and the current item =0

```
 package com.example.tstswipe;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView.FindListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    // State number of pages
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }

    // Set each screen's content
    public Object instantiateItem(View container, int position) {
        Context context = container.getContext();
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);
        // Add elements
        TextView textItem = new TextView(context);


        Button buttonItem = new Button(context);
        buttonItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.phone");
               // myFancyMethod(v);
           }
        });


        switch (position) {
        case 0:
           textItem.setText("First Screen");
           break;
        case 1:
           textItem.setText("Second Screen");
           break;
        case 2:
            textItem.setText("Third Screen");
            break;


        case 3:
        textItem.setText("Fourth Screen");
        break;
       case 4:
        textItem.setText("Fifth Screen");
        break;
    }
    layout.addView(textItem);
    ((ViewPager) container).addView(layout, 0); // This is the line I added
    return layout;
}
public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
    ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);
}
public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
    return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
}
public Parcelable saveState() {
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: Please post you logcat message and activity code

Comment: Did you add your second activity to the manifest?

Comment: Logcat? What command causes the problem? Code?

Comment: in logcat it doesn't lead me to the line that indicate the error

Comment: yeah i did,, i add to the manifest

Answer (score 0):

You state that the error is `could not find class "com.example.MyPagerAdapter"` but the fully qualified name of the class you posted is `com.example.tstswipe.MyPagerAdapter`.

Comment: sorry it's my mistake the error was could not find class com.example.tstswipe.MyPagerAdapter.

Comment: this is exactly what i found in logcat java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tstswipe/com.example.tstswipe.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class android.support.v4.view.ViewPager